# Is there any programmatic approach to inject nhibernate UserTypes?

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, decimal

I have an application developed with Nhibernate and Microsoft Sql Server, but now I´m trying to migrate it to SQLite. I have found a problem with SQLite, it doesn´t give me an appropriate fixed point number format and accurate arithmetic for money values. So, to resolve this problem I simulate fixed point behaviour writing custom IResultTransformer and UserType (FixedPointDecimalUserType). Also, I want to share mappings between applications.

I have an extension to inject my UserType in properties and components mappings where type is decimal

```
<property name="Quantity" not-null="true" type="Decimal(8,3)"/>
```

My extension is like this:

```
public static class NHExtensions
    {

        public static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration AdaptToSQLite(this NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration)
        {
            if (configuration.ClassMappings.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Es necesario añadir el assembly al configuration antes de llamar a este método");

            if (configuration.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect].IsIn(typeof(SQLiteDialect).FullName, typeof(SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName))
            {
                foreach (var mapping in configuration.ClassMappings)
                    foreach (var property in mapping.PropertyIterator)
                        AdaptProperty(property);

                foreach (var mapping in configuration.CollectionMappings)
                    How to get inject FixedPointUserType?

            }
            return configuration;
        }

        public static void AdaptProperty(Property property)
        {
            if (property.IsComposite)
            {
                var component = property.Value as Component;
                component.PropertyIterator.Each(AdaptProperty);
            }

            if (property.Type.GetType() == typeof(DecimalType))
            {
                var simpleValue = property.Value as SimpleValue;
                if (simpleValue != null)        
                    simpleValue.TypeName = typeof(FixedPointDecimalUserType).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I find a NHibernate.Mapping.List<> I don´t know how to inject my UserType, for example for SoldProduct.

```
<list name="Addins" table="TicketLineAddin" fetch="join">
    <key column="TicketLineId" ..../>
    <index column="AddinIndex"/>
    <composite-element class="Domain.Catalogue.SoldProduct, Domain">
        <property name="ProductId" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="ProductName" not-null="true" length="120"/>
        <property name="Price" not-null="true" type="Decimal(12,3)"/>
        <property name="VatId" column="VatId"  not-null="true"/>
        <property name="VatRate" column="VatRate"  not-null="true" type="Decimal(12,3)"/>
        <property name="PreparationType" not-null="true" type="Common.Ordering.PreparationType, Common"/>
        <property name="PriceListId" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="PrintMode" not-null="true"/>
    </composite-element>
</list>
```

An alternative could be a different custom UserType implementation for SQL Server and SQLite application and replace all decimal types in my .hbm files

```
<property name="Quantity" not-null="true" type="FixedPointUserType"/>
```

but, is there any programmatic approach to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var mapping in config.CollectionMappings)
{
    if (mapping.Element.Type.IsComponentType)
    {
        var subtypes = ((ComponentType)mapping.Element.Type).Subtypes;
        for (int i =0; i < subtypes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (subtypes[i].GetType() == typeof(DecimalType))
            {
                subtypes[i] = new FixedPointDecimalUserType();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cant test it though

Answer (score 0):

With this code works fine, thanks

```
configuration.BuildMappings();

    ...
foreach(...)
    if (mapping.Element.Type.IsComponentType)
    {
        var subtypes = ((ComponentType)elementType).Subtypes;
        for (var i = 0; i < subtypes.Length; i++)
            if (subtypes[i].GetType() == typeof(DecimalType))
                subtypes[i] = new CustomType(typeof(FixedPointDecimalUserType), new Dictionary<string, string>());

    }
```